# get bitmap information from bitmap stored in drawable folder

Tags: android, file, bitmap, drawable

I wanna read in a bitmap that I have in my drawable folder and store it as a Bitmap variable so that I can set it as a background. Would the best way to do this be using a "file reader"? like

```
  Bitmap decodeFile (String pathName) method
```

Or is there a way to just set it like this:

```
  Bitmap bmp = R.drawable."bitmapFileName";
```

(I have tried this but returns an int, just wondering if I was on the right track)

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `R.drawable."bitmapFileName"` is, indeed, just an integer, for it is an index (static integer) at your project's R class (see more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)). You can load your bitmap from the resources's folder like this:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourBitmap);
```

I found this code at the [Android Development Community](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=1530).

Answer (score 6):

I usually use the assets folder

```
InputStream is = parentActivity.getResources().getAssets().open(iconFile);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(is);
```

then just `yourView.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);`

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to load a drawable or bitmap by name. Here is an example:

```
public Drawable getImageByName(String nameOfTheDrawable, Activity a){
    Drawable drawFromPath;
    int path = a.getResources().getIdentifier(nameOfTheDrawable, 
                                    "drawable", "com.mycompany.myapp"); 

    Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), path, options);

    drawFromPath = new BitmapDrawable(source);  

    return drawFromPath;
}
```

You can of course return Bitmap instead a drawable.

> Drawbale d =  getImageByName("mageFileName", this);

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * You can get Bitmap from drawable resource id in the following way
 */
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)context.getResources()
        .getDrawable(drawableId);
bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```